# Customize “subsription option” string generated by WooCommerce Subscribe All The Things plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add text through `functions.php` just after `subscription-price">`

I can do this with direct code editing, but need help to apply filter through `functions.php` without changing orignal files.

```php
$option_description = apply_filters( 'wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', '<span class="' . $option_price_class . ' subscription-price">Text Here' . $sub_price_html . '</span>', $sub_price_html, $has_price_filter, false === $force_subscription, $product, $subscription_scheme );

        $option = array(
            'class'       => 'subscription-option',
            'value'       => $scheme_key,
            'selected'    => $default_subscription_scheme_option_value === $scheme_key,
            'description' => $option_description,
            'data'        => $option_data
        );
```

something like that

```php
add_filter( 'wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', 'add_custom_text_to_subscription_option');

function add_custom_text_to_subscription_option( $product) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suffice, basically anything you assign to the `$option_descreption` variable will be displayed

Replace `Your new text` in this answer, depending on your needs

```php
function filter_wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description( $option_description, $sub_price_html, $has_price_filter, $force_subscription, $product, $subscription_scheme ) {
    // Class
    $option_price_class = 'subscription-option';
    
    // New description
    $option_description = '<span class="' . $option_price_class . ' subscription-price">Your new Text ' . $sub_price_html . '</span>';
    
    return $option_description;
}
add_filter( 'wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', 'filter_wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', 10, 6 );
```