# Customize “one time option” string generated by WooCommerce Subscribe All The Things plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Based on [Customize “subsription option” string generated by WooCommerce Subscribe All The Things plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66769403/11987538) answer code, this is my attempt:

```php
function filter_wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description( 
$option_description, $sub_price_html, $has_price_filter, $force_subscription, $product, $subscription_scheme ) {
// Class
$option_price_class = 'subscription-option';

// New description
$option_description = '<span>Subscription: </span> 
<span>' . $sub_price_html . '</span>';

return $option_description;
}
add_filter( 'wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', 'filter_wcsatt_single_product_subscription_option_description', 10, 6 );
```

---

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice, basically anything you assign to the `$none_string` variable will be displayed

```php
function filter_wcsatt_single_product_one_time_option_description( $none_string, $product ) {
    $none_string = $product->get_price_html();
    
    return $none_string;
}
add_filter( 'wcsatt_single_product_one_time_option_description', 'filter_wcsatt_single_product_one_time_option_description', 10, 2 );
```

---

The main price above "choose a purchase plan" is added by WooCommerce, and not by the WCSATT plugin. So to hide it, you can use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['price_html'] = '';
    
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_woocommerce_available_variation', 10, 3 );
```